# what does mean "NULL" in f-string specification in python?

Tags: python

I open [python specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) at chapter 2. Lexical analysis and found

```
format_spec       ::=  (literal_char | NULL | replacement_field)*
literal_char      ::=  <any code point except "{", "}" or NULL>
```

What does mean `NULL`?
It is not specified any where before

Comment: In the context of `literal_char`, a plain reading would mean that it refers to the NUL character itself -- the character with codepoint 0 (which ANSI-compatible terminals don't even print at all).

Comment: I'm not sure that's up to date anyway; PEP 701 significantly changed the grammar with regards to f-strings.

Comment: What semantic does mean for example `f'{var:\x00}'`? Why this NULL explicitly specified?

Comment: That's not a null character in the f-string literal itself, though; it's just 4 ASCII characters forming part of the literal.

Comment: I've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/116881) to get it either explained or fixed.

Comment: For what it's worth, the actual grammar doesn't appear to directly reference `NULL` in the same way the docs do, though it might be handled in some backhanded way by the definition of the tokenizer's `FSTRING_MIDDLE` token type, which I can't seem to find.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a reference, but I believe it refers to an empty string (though it doesn't seem necessary).

The format spec is the portion of a replacement field following the `:`, and it can be literally nothing.

```
>>> x = 3
>>> f'{x:}'
'3'
```

UPDATE: the documentation has been updated as of 2024-03-18, though I'm not sure when the update will go live. (A preview is available at https://cpython-previews--116885.org.readthedocs.build/en/116885/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals.) The new rule for `format_spec` will read

```
format_spec       ::=  (literal_char | replacement_field)*
```

and `literal_char` remains

```
literal_char      ::=  <any code point except "{", "}" or NULL>
```

where `NULL` does, in fact, refer to the null character U+0000. There are three characters that are not allowed to be used as a literal character, and U+0000 is one of them.

Comment: Doesn't `*` being zero-or-more already give you that indication?

Comment: It does, but I'm struggling to think why this would refer to the null character, as you can't put them in source code to begin with.

Comment: It *might* be there because you can construct format specs through nested interpolation. For example, `x = '\x00'; y = f'{z:{x}}'` is valid, and might even run without errors if `z.__format__` can handle that format spec.

Comment: That's why `replacement_field` is in the rule for `format_spec`; it doesn't explain `NULL`.

Comment: Indeed, and the result after processing nested replacements doesn't have to be a lexically valid format spec - for example, `x = '{'; y = f'{z:{x}}'` is valid, and hits no lexing or parsing issues.